# Разделение логики одного файла JS для разных url

Tags: javascript

Есть две html страницы. Главная и форма. Один файл js (для уменьшения http-запросов) с логикой для этих двух страниц. JS содержит свои обработчики событий отдельно для главной и отдельно для формы. Но файл то js один. И находясь на одной из html страниц js не находит элементы которые находятся на другой странице.
Какая существует практика в таких ситуациях ?

```
if (location.. === 'targetPage') {
    // выполнить..
}
```

Через location ??

Comment: "для уменьшения http-запросов" - это не та оптимизация, которая здесь нужна. Сделайте два файла.

Comment: Тогда - три файла.

Comment: Спасибо.
В таком случае получается, что для каждой странице нужен свой бандл js-файла.
А если к каждому бандлу js-файла мне нужно будет добавить логику хедера, которая используется на каждой странице. То в этом случае лучше использовать дополнительные инструменты "сборки" - это, к примеру webpack и gulp.
Не подскажите какие плагины в таком случае нужны ?
Предполагаю, что на выходе каждый бандл будет иметь имя в виде хеша для дальнейшего эффективного использования кеша браузера при внесении изменений в эти бандлы js.

Comment: Всё есть в доках webpack, нашел